# How to override a display:none property applied to parent element in specific child elements

Tags: html, css

Ive been scratching my head over this one for a while and cant figure out why its not working. Im basically trying to hide some specific content on a page using only CSS - for this bit of work i wont have access to the on page HTML but will be able to inject CSS at will.

Okay so ive got a basic HTML structure as follows:

```
<div id="content-body">
<p> want this to stay </p>    
<h2>want this to stay</h2>
<p> want this to stay </p>
<p> want this to stay </p>
<p> want this removed </p>    
<h2>want this removed</h2>
<p> want this removed </p>
<p> want this removed </p>
</div>
```

Ive put together the following CSS to remove the entire "content-body" element and then override this on specific children, however it doesnt seem to work.

```
#content-body {display:none}

p:nth-child(1) {display:block !important}
h2:nth-child(2) {display:block}
p:nth-child(3) {display:block}
p:nth-child(4) {display:block}
```

the important tag doesn't seem to make any difference. Is there anything incorrect about how i've formatted this? (the actual page has a lot more HTML than the example so removing everything through CSS is a lot easier than individually selecting elements, although i may need to do this instead)

Comment: if a parent element is hidden, all of it is hidden, there is no way to make any of its children visible without making the parent visible.

Comment: @Jimmy OP cannot change markup and only wants to do this via CSS.

Comment: gah yeah thats pretty obvious, should have realised that... cheers, ill use a more specific selector to apply the initial display:none

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're hiding the parent element by calling:

```css
#content-body {display:none}
```

So all of the children will be hidden as well regardless of how you target them. What you need to do instead is hide the `p` and `h2` elements within `#content-body` and then overwrite the ones you want to show by using `nth-of-type` instead of `nth-child` (since you want to target the 1st `h2` and the 3rd `p`, etc.) like so:

```css
#content-body p, #content-body h2 {
    display: none;
}    

#content-body p:nth-of-type(1),
#content-body p:nth-of-type(2),
#content-body p:nth-of-type(3),
#content-body h2:nth-of-type(1) {
    display: block;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ta0ckm68/)

Comment: wouldn't it be easier just to add 2 classes: .show for display block, and .hide for display none?, on elements that have display block/none applied to them? it should be easier this way

Comment: @Crispy-George read OP's question: `Im basically trying to hide some specific content on a page using only CSS - for this bit of work i wont have access to the on page HTML but will be able to inject CSS at will.`

Comment: right-o, missed that part, then this is the way to go for sure

Comment: aye, @jmore009 pointed out that earlier, I read it in a hurry and skipped some content, sorry about that

Comment: fantastic, cheers jmore. Bit of a silly mistake on my part, but im getting there!

Comment: @Ash no problem, yes you were close. Glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

You can select all direct children with global selector, then you can override that:

```css
#content-body > * { display: none }

#content-body p:nth-child(1),
#content-body h2:nth-child(2),
#content-body p:nth-child(3),
#content-body p:nth-child(4) { display: block }
```

Example here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/85f0ee63/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Your first selector `#content-body { display: none; }` is hiding everything as it is the container. First hide all of the elements individually by targeting `p` and `h2` then selectively show elements with [nth-of-type selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type).

```css
#content-body p,
#content-body h2 { display: none }

#content-body p:nth-of-type(1) { display: block }
#content-body h2:nth-of-type(1) { display:block }
#content-body p:nth-of-type(2) { display:block }
#content-body p:nth-of-type(3) { display:block }
```

```html
<div id="content-body">
    <p>want this to stay</p>    
    <h2>want this to stay</h2>
    <p>want this to stay</p>
    <p>want this to stay</p>
    <p>want this removed</p>    
    <h2>want this removed</h2>
    <p>want this removed</p>
    <p>want this removed</p>
</div>
```